# Read json file from url without hyperlinks

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, url, hyperlink

I am using the following command to extract the information embedded in [the following webpage](https://www.mitomap.org/foswiki/bin/view/MITOMAP/MutationsRNA): (eventually what I want to do is to extract the information in the dataframe displayed in the above mentioned webpage).

```
import urllib.request, json 
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.mitomap.org/foswiki/bin/view/MITOMAP/MutationsRNA") as url:
    data = url.read().decode()
```

We can see, however, that there are lots of hyperlinks in the data frame. Take for instance the column `Locus`. If I print the observations under `Locus` it will be displayed as shown below:

```
"<a href='/MITOMAP/GenomeLoci#MTTF'>MT-TF</a>"
```

Which indicates that is a hyperlink. None the less, I would like to have the **text** displayed (in the present example `MT-TF`) in my final data frame.

Is there any argument that I can pass to `urllib.request.urlopen()` to **extract only the text (and not the hyperlink)** or any other way I can go about doing that?

Comment: No, you will have to use an html parser (eg BeautifulSoup) for that

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can now get rid of the text, keeping only the text without regex or anything like that?